# How to count number of times strings appear in a column from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a few dataframes that look like this that follow the same format.

this is df1:

```
    country ticker 
0   US      MSFT
1   US      AAPL
2   GERMANY NSU.DE
3   SG      D05.SI
4   AUS     WOW.AX
```

this is df2:

```
    country ticker 
0   HK      0700.HK
1   HK      1337.HK
2   SWISS   NESN.SW
3   SG      OV8.SI
```

The dataframes are saved into csv files with multiple sheets. I can cycle over them easily.

I want to create a frame or dictionary or variables that counts the total times the countries appear like this.

```
    country count
0   US      2
1   GERMANY 1
2   SG      2
3   AUS     1
4   SWISS   1
5   HK      2
```

How can I do that? It doesnt have to be a dataframe.

Comment: `a = dict(df['country'].value_counts(dropna=False))`, should give you a dict obj like `{"US": 2, ...}`, you can loop across your sheets and update your `dict` object to get all counts.

Comment: doesnt work, just gives me the number of times the last instance of something appears

Comment: Use pd.concat to concatenate the dataframes then use 'value_counts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group each df by country, and then merge all dfs and sum counts:

```
#group by countries and get count
df1 = csvDf1.groupby('country').count().reset_index()
df2 = csvDf2.groupby('country').count().reset_index()
df3 = csvDf3.groupby('country').count().reset_index()

#merge all dfs
combinedDf = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['country'])
combinedDf = combinedDf.merge(df3, how='outer', on=['country'])

#sum all counts per country
combinedDf ['total']=combinedDf .iloc[:,1:].sum(1)
combinedDf  = combinedDf[['country', 'total']]
```